# Ifelse with multiple conditions in sapply function

Tags: r, if-statement, apply, sapply

I need to check each row in two columns for the two conditions in the dataframe (basically, I'm substracting each row in one pair of columns from each row in another pair of columns to get two certain values (one of which is time interval), see code). The expected result is another column with 1 if both conditions are satisfied and 0 otherwise.

I've tried:

```
sapply(trades1, function(x) x$indicator3 <- x %>% ifelse(indicator2 - indicator == -1 & difftime(date2, date, units = "min"== 1), 1, 0))
```

This gives me

```
 Error in ifelse(., indicator2 - indicator == -1 & difftime(date2, date,  : 
  unused argument (0)
```

Comment: There's a solution given already but fyi the error is because `ifelse` takes 3 arguments. The purpose of `%>%` is that it assigns the left-hand-side as the first argument to the function on the right-hand-side. You then add 3 more arguments for a total of 4, i.e. one more than needed, which is why you get an "unused argument" error.

Comment: Is there a way to link all the columns to x without ```%>%```? I've tried $ operator, but it gave me another error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `trades1` is a data.frame`, we may need

```
with(x, as.integer(((indicator2 - indicator) == -1) & 
     (difftime(date2, date, units = "min")== 1)))
```

Make sure the `difftime` braces are closed